Order in which covariates are measured in an observational study - causal inference
I want to model hba1c levels for a group of type 1 diabetes patients. I have data which are extracted from a register, and my goal is to answer whether a treatment intervention decreases hba1c levels on average. I am (trying) to use causal inference, where the average treatment effect is calculated using potential outcomes.
Hence my research question is
$$
E\{E (Y|A=1,W)-E(Y|A=0,W) \},
$$
where $Y$ is outcome, $A$ is binary treatment and $W$ are baseline variables.
The assumptions are
$$
\begin{array}{cllc}
1 & \text{ Consistency:} & A=a \Rightarrow Y=Y^a,\\
2 & \text{ Exchangeability:} &  A \perp Y^a|W (\perp \textit{read } \text{ "independence"}),\\
3 & \text{ Positivity:} & P(A=a|W=w)>0 \text{ when } P(W=w)>0.
\end{array}
$$
I believe these assumptions are commonly used in causal inference.
Now I present my issue, which goes on the order in which the data are measured.
As I wrote, the data come from a registry, and isn't from a randomized control. The causal chain obviously require that the outcome (hba1c levels) are measured after the treatment intervention (for those who receive it), and not before - hence making it meaningless to try and assess an effect of treatment. Also baseline variables are measured before the observed outcome.
BUT for various records in data I have that the treatment intervention is given $\textit{before}$ some baseline variables are measured (i.e. non-deterministic variables such as blood pressure etc. which changes over time). Thus there is a chance that the treatment effect is hidden or exaggerated through baseline variables.
Is there a way to overcome this, since I'm guessing this problem has been encountered before within register analysis.
Best

If I understand your setup correctly, you’re working with a binary point exposure variable $A$, an outcome $Y$, and an adjustment set $\{W, X\}$ that is sufficient for blocking confounding based on either background knowledge or causal graphical assumptions. However, for some units, $X$ may have been measured in the post-exposure period only, creating a potential issue since $X$ could in fact represent two distinct causal nodes: pre-exposure $X_0$ and post-exposure $X_1$.
Overlooking this time-order distinction can introduce post-exposure bias when adjusting for $X_1$ if it's causally affected by $A$ itself, is a mediator, or a descendant of one, as in the following causal graph:
$$
(W, X_0) \rightarrow A \rightarrow X_1 \rightarrow Y
$$
$$
A \rightarrow Y \leftarrow (W, X_0) \rightarrow X_1
$$
Adjusting for $X_1$ would not induce bias if it’s not a descendant of $A$. Yet, the main issue arises from missing data on $X_0$ for some units, especially if $W$ alone is not sufficient to block confounding without $X_0$.
In this case, you might treat $X_0$ as a confounder subjected to a missingness mechanism and incorporate a missing data model to augment the causal graph. Two common models are:
Missing Completely at Random (MCAR)
Let $R_0$ be a binary indicator for missingness on $X_0$, where $R_0=1$ implies $X_0$ is observed, and $R_0=0$ means it’s missing. If $R_0$ is independent of all other nodes, then $R_0 \perp X_0$ and so we can ignore units without $X_0$. This is, one can perform complete case analysis (CCA), which identifies the ATE as:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left\{\Delta_a \mathbb{E}[Y\mid A=a, W, X_0, R_0=1] \mid R_0=1\right\},
$$
where $\Delta_a f(a) = f(1) - f(0)$.
Missing at Random (MAR)
Suppose the missingness indicator $R_0$ depends (non-deterministically) on (some of) the fully observed covariates $W$. For instance, $R_0$ might vary by gender, and men could have a higher probability than women of having $X$ measure post-exposure rather than pre-exposure. In this case, if one has that $R_0 \perp X_0 \mid W$, as shown in the following causal graph:
$$
(W, X_0) \rightarrow A \rightarrow X_1 \rightarrow Y
$$
$$
A \rightarrow Y \leftarrow (W, X_0) \rightarrow X_1
$$
$$
X_0 \leftarrow W \rightarrow R_0
$$
Then the ATE is identifiable by marginalizing in two steps:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left\{\Delta_a \mathbb{E}[Y \mid A=a, W, X_0, R_0=1] \mid W, R_0=1\right\}\right\}
$$
where the second expectation standardizes over $p(X_0 \mid W, R_0=1)$, and the outermost expectation is over $p(W)$, leveraging the factorization $p(X_0 \mid W, R_0=1)\, p(W) = p(X_0, W)$.
Alternatively, you might impute missing values of $X_0$ and treat the imputed values as observed, but care should be taken in specifying the imputation model. For instance, you could use $X_1$ in the imputation model for $X_0$ if you have some enough units for which you measured both pre- and post-exposure $X$.

Thanks for your response Johan!! Really helped me. Just to clarify, non of the units are measured pre- and post-exposure. Some are measured pre-exposure, and the remaining are post-exposure.
Basically I want to use X1 in the place of X0 if I know that both were measured 12 months before Y, but then I'd rely on what you write: "Adjusting for X1 would not induce bias if it’s not a descendant of A."
Perhaps I've been too naive to get valid results from this dataset which has a bad design, since some have treatment A before X is measured (X0), and others have treatment after X is measured (X1).
